# Prestashop - PSWebServiceLibrary - Webservice CRUD attribute complete list

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to know if is there a complete list of Webservice CRUD attributes?

For example, following the documentation http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial if I want to add a new customer (using PSWebServiceLibrary) and the attributes are:

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <customer>
        <id_default_group/>
        <id_lang format="isUnsignedId"/>
        <newsletter_date_add/>
        <ip_registration_newsletter/>
        <last_passwd_gen readOnly="true"/>
        <secure_key format="isMd5" readOnly="true"/>
        <deleted format="isBool"/>
        <passwd required="true" maxSize="255" format="isPasswd"/>
        <lastname required="true" maxSize="255" format="isCustomerName"/>
        <firstname required="true" maxSize="255" format="isCustomerName"/>
        <email required="true" maxSize="255" format="isEmail"/>
        <id_gender format="isUnsignedId"/>
        <birthday format="isBirthDate"/>
        <newsletter format="isBool"/>
        <optin format="isBool"/>
        <website format="isUrl"/>
        <company format="isGenericName"/>
        <siret format="isGenericName"/>
        <ape format="isApe"/>
        <outstanding_allow_amount format="isFloat"/>
        <show_public_prices format="isBool"/>
        <id_risk format="isUnsignedInt"/>
        <max_payment_days format="isUnsignedInt"/>
        <active format="isBool"/>
        <note maxSize="65000" format="isCleanHtml"/>
        <is_guest format="isBool"/>
        <id_shop format="isUnsignedId"/>
        <id_shop_group format="isUnsignedId"/>
        <date_add format="isDate"/>
        <date_upd format="isDate"/>
        <reset_password_token maxSize="40" format="isSha1"/>
        <reset_password_validity format="isDateOrNull"/>
        <associations>
            <groups nodeType="group" api="groups">
                <group>
                    <id/>
                </group>
            </groups>
        </associations>
    </customer>
</prestashop>
```

Here I can see that some attribute:

1. are required (required="true")
2. have a max size (maxSize="255")
3. is boolean (format="isBool")
4. ecc...

but some others I don't understand them, for example:

1. format="isBirthDate" is aaaa-mm-dd or dd/mm/aaaa?
2. format="isDate" is the same of "isBirthDate" or not?
3. format "isGenericName" or "isCustomerName" accept all chars?
4. format="isApe" what is it?
5. format="isFloat" is 0.00 or 0.000 or 0,00?
6. ecc...

I didn't find documentation on web that explain each attribute, someone know if is there?

Answer (score 0):

They are methods from validate class.

Source :
https://github.com/pal/prestashop/blob/master/classes/Validate.php

**isBirthDate" is aaaa-mm-dd or dd/mm/aaaa?**

***aaaa-mm-dd***

**"isDate()" is the same of "isBirthDate()" or not?**

no isDate() check date validity with checkdate() function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

isBirthDate() check for birthDate validity and check if the year of birth is possible

**format "isGenericName" or "isCustomerName" accept all chars?**

No

**isApe()**

it's an old method to validate company number (https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-1.5/blob/master/classes/Validate.php)

**isFloat()**

Check for a float number validity